# How to repair crack in T1 11 siding

Tags: siding, crack

I bought this house about a year ago, it was built in 2003. Since I bought, I noticed a large-ish crack forming in it. Can I just tap this in with a hammer and use some resin, or is there a better way to do it?

[image: crack in siding]
[image: close up of crack in siding]

Comment: That doesn't really look like fiber cement siding. Fiber cement looks like hardibacker board. Your picture looks more like T-111 siding. It looks like wood showing in the crack. Fiber cement has a lot of cement in it and can snap or shatter and doesn't look like wood when broken. It is usually only ¼"-5/16" thick. That could be some kind of engineered lumber though.

Comment: I am having a hard time with the photo but it looks like wood to me. In my area wood t111 can delaminate if it is not sealed well. Other issues are bad paint jobs causing paint to lift but from what I could see it looks like delamination. In some cases it can be repaired but most the section needs to be replaced.

Comment: @ArchonOSX Thank you for the input, it's very useful. Before this I had a hard time even searching for relevant information.

Comment: I replaced all the T1-11 with hardiplank. Expensive, but the alternative is a soggy rotting house, so it's worth it.